# Where to call Robospice's shouldStop() method in Service class

Tags: android, robospice

I'm using [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) library. It's really perfect library. But i don't understand something.

I want to perform request in Service class. Service has `onStart` method and i can call `spiceManager.start(this)` in `onStart()`. But Service hasn't got onStop. Where should i call `spiceManager.shouldStop()`?

```
public class SomeService extends Service {

    private SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(
            JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService.class);

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        spiceManager.start(getApplicationContext());
        performSomeRequest(getApplicationContext(), spiceManager,
                new SomeRequestListener());
    }
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Service.onDestroy()` looks like the right place to do this.

> Called by the system to notify a Service that it is no longer used and is being removed.  The service should clean up an resources it holds (threads, registered  receivers, etc) at this point.